# Angular Template reference throwing error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I got two arrays variables, which needs to render same html content.

```
notification = [...]
disruptionNotification = [...]
```

Below is my HTML,

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let notification of notifications; let i = index">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="notification"></ng-container>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let notification of disruptionNotification; let i = index">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="notification"></ng-container>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-template #notification>
      <tag-notification [type]="notification.type">
      <ng-container *ngIf="notification.titleLink && notification.title; else bwcNotificationTitleOnly">
       ....
      </ng-container>
    </tag-notification>
  </ng-template>
```

But after rendering, I'm this error `TypeError: templateRef.createEmbeddedView is not a function`

StackBlitz Link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bxcmrp

Expected result should be,

```
This is Title
This is Title
This is disruptionNotifications
This is disruptionNotifications
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle reproducing the issue.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bxcmrp

Comment: In my case the error was due to me forgetting * (asterisk) before ngTemplateOutlet

Answer (score 0):

Whatever element you reference in the *ngIf else clause can’t be any arbitrary component, but it must be a ng-template.